# In Windows, how do I find the geotags for videos shot in iOS?

Tags: windows, ios

I have footage shot with the stock iPhone Camera app (5S running iOS 8.x).  Inside iOS Photos, I can see the geo coordinates where each video was shot.  However, I don't know how to get at that information once I'm in Windows and looking at the same .mov file.  I'm on Windows 10, for what it's worth.

Answer (score 1):

Use [exiftool](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/), a command-line tool. GUI available from [here](http://u88.n24.queensu.ca/exiftool/forum/index.php/topic,2750.0.html).

Relevant feature:

> Reads EXIF, GPS, IPTC, XMP, JFIF, MakerNotes, GeoTIFF, ICC Profile,
>   Photoshop IRB, FlashPix, AFCP, ID3 and more.

Should look like this, in readout:

> GPSCoordinates                  : 20.884100° N, 21.319300° E, 17 m
>   Above Sea Level